# Deleting cookies / looping login & logout request

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm making a project to log into a website than instantly log out and do it all over again. Well my problem is cookies I'm quite unsure how to log out correctly and than resend. Closing the app and restarting it logs the user back in again so its obvious cookies are being cleared then.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest request;
        string postData;
        byte[] byteArray;
        Stream dataStream;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.********/index.php");

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                postData = "param=example&param=0&param=bigboy";
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
                httpWReq.Method = "POST";
                httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
                httpWReq.KeepAlive = false;

                httpWReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

What can be done to achieve such a looping process?

Comment: "so its obvious cookies are being cleared then". "not" being cleared you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following psuedocode should work for you.

Note the reuse of the same CookieContainer object on the login AND the logout requests.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();


            HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.********/index.php");
            loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

            // Configure login request headers and data, write to request stream, etc.

            HttpWebResponse loginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse();


            HttpWebRequest logoutRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.********/logout.php");
            logoutRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

            // Configure logout request headers and data, write to request stream, etc.

            HttpWebResponse logoutResponse = (HttpWebResponse)logoutRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Give something like this a try and let me know how it goes.

Also: Try debugging the response objects' Cookie property. It's a CookieCollection, *not* a CookieContainer as per the request. But it should still provide useful debug information if you need to take a closer look at exactly what's going on. Example here: http://goo.gl/L2MMrj

Comment: Hi, I completely forgot about this but thank you very much I will try it in an hour or so! marked as answer because it looks right to me and you seem to have a well understanding.